# iOS-Edge-Line not loading icons

Tags: angular, typescript, user-interface, fonts, icons

We are using Angular 11+ and using iOS-Edge-Line icons library. Usually it's working but sometimes icons not loading. On random page loads or refreshing the page strange characters are displayed instead of icons.

Some example images:

[image]

[image]

This is the import code icons library

```css
[class^='icon-'],
[class*=' icon-'] {
  /* use !important to prevent issues with browser extensions that change fonts */
  font-family: 'iOS-Edge-Line' !important;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;
  /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.icon-D-Cube:before {
  content: '\e901';
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'iOS-Edge-Line';
  src: local('iOS-Edge-Line'), url('/assets/fonts/iOS-Edge-Line.eot'),
    url('/assets/fonts/iOS-Edge-Line.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('/assets/fonts/iOS-Edge-Line.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('/assets/fonts/iOS-Edge-Line.woff') format('woff'),
    url('/assets/fonts/iOS-Edge-Line.svg?#iOS-Edge-Line') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  unicode-range: U+0901-EDAF;
}
```